# Is /home/user/.config really necessary for local npm installations?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to do a local npm installation, that is, copy lots of nodejs modules to a local node_modules folder. I'm in a docker container that does not have /home/user. I could create it, obviously, but is it really necessary? Currently, a local npm installation is giving me this error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/lz'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/lz'
npm ERR!   cause: { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/lz' errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', syscall: 'mkdir', path: '/home/lz' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir \'/home/lz\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/lz' }
npm ERR!
```

Is .config really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The default cache folder for npm is `~/.npm` ([npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cache)). It is necessary to have the cache folder and cannot completely disable the cache folder, since the npm installer uses it to unpacks package tarballs from the cache, and so every package to be installed must at some point find its way into the cache.

However, you can change it into other folder, such as `/tmp` so that no need to create home folder:

```
npm config set cache /tmp --global
```